# How to combine two entry values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In the dataset, the column "Erf Size" has entries like 1 733 and 1 539 etc. Note that the Dtype of this "Erf Size" column is object.

I would like to join these 1 733 and 1 539 into 1733 and 1539 etc.
[original dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M17WW.png)

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG7Ek.png)

Comment: Can you please show us your expected output ? Not sure I understand correct what you want to achieve. What is "entries[dataset]" ?

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope you it's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can fix this with `pd.to_numeric`. This will change the data type to a number value and I expect it to remove the space.

Or else you can try:

```
df1['Erf Size'].str.strip()
```

that will remove the space, which will work in your dataset as it's an object.

Answer (score 0):

I would use list comprehension to clean string and then if you want to can convert dtype to numeric value:

```
df['Erf Size'] = [x.replace(' ', '').replace('.', '').replace(',', '') for x in df['Erf Size']]
```